# Simple Image View not working Android Studios 3.1.1 All other work fine. My Log cat

Tags: android, imageview

--------- beginning of crash
08-03 02:12:29.254 29641-29641/com.example.riyaz.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.riyaz.myapplication, PID: 29641
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 298598412 byte allocation with 10742036 free bytes and 240MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2636)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2541)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:152)
        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:140)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.riyaz.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-03 02:12:29.260 29641-29641/com.example.riyaz.myapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
08-03 02:12:29.677 29641-29641/com.example.riyaz.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29641 SIG: 9

Comment: Every Thing builds fine but app crashes in device.No Error While Building other text view and button programs work fine.

Comment: JAVA FILE:

package com.example.riyaz.myapplication;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: No Error while Build Every thing works fine but application crashes in device.

Comment: XML FILE:
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/g"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

Comment: In Design For xml image appears in preview but application crashes in device while instant run.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your Image file(@drawable/g)

1-Build+Clean Project
2- Run again
If this does not worke! replace image file

Comment: What sort of problem? The indication in the question is some sort of memory problem - might the image be too big? Are you certain that replacing the image file (with any image) will help?